# Solving simultaneous equation in R

Tags: r

I want to solve the following simultaneous equations using R:

```
# -0.9x+0.01y+0.001z+0.001n=0
# 0.9x-0.82y+0.027z+0.027n=0
# 0x+0.81y+(0.243-1)z+0.243n=0
# 0x+0y+0.729z+(0.729-1)n=0
# x+y+z+n=1
```

I tried:

```
A <- matrix(data=c(-0.9,0.01,0.001,0.001,0.9,-0.82,0.027,0.027,0,0.81,0.243-1,0.243,0,0,0.729,0.729-1,1,1,1,1), nrow=5, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)    
b <- matrix(data=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1), nrow=5, ncol=1, byrow=FALSE)
round(solve(A, b), 4)
```

and it caught error:

```
Error in solve.default(A, b) : 'a' (5 x 4) must be square
```

What does the error mean? Is this function only applicable to square matrix?

---

Edit:

I removed the last equation and tried:

```
A <- matrix(data=c(-0.9,0.01,0.001,0.001,0.9,-0.82,0.027,0.027,0,0.81,0.243-1,0.243,0,0,0.729,0.729-1), nrow=4, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)    
b <- matrix(data=c(0, 0, 0, 0), nrow=4, ncol=1, byrow=FALSE)
A;b;
round(solve(A, b), 4)
```

which caught error:

```
Error in solve.default(A, b) : Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[4,4] = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have 5 linear equations (rows of your matrix) and only 4 columns (variables), then your problem is overdetermined and in general it can't be solved. Consider a smaller example: `x+y=1; x-2*y=2; 3*x-5=0`. Once you use the first two equations:

```
(1) x+y=1        → y=1-x
(2) x-2*(1-x)=2  → 3*x-2=2 → x=4/3  ## substitute (1) into second eq.
(3) → y=-1/3
```

you have a solution for x and y (x=4/3, y=-1/3), so the last equation is either redundant or makes your solution impossible (in this case, the latter: `3*x-5 = -1 != 5`).

On the other hand, if you have fewer rows than columns, then your system is underdetermined and you can't get a unique answer.

So the number of matrix rows must equal the number of columns → you can only do this with a square matrix. This is not a limitation of the R function, it's about the underlying math of linear equations ...

In your *specific* case the problem is that the sum of the first four rows of your matrix add up to zero, so these are *redundant*. As you found out, just dropping the last equation doesn't help.  But if you drop **one of the redundant rows** you can get an answer.

```r
solve(A[-4,],b[-4])
```

Note you get the same answer whether you drop row 1, 2, 3, or 4.

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you for your answer. In this case if I remove the redundant equation, would I be able to solve the equations? I tried this but caught another error, please see edited question. Thank you in advance.